# iOS: My storyboard is landscape and project is set to landscape but still wrong in simulator

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to make a landscape iPad app.
I did below 3 things. the simulator orientation is landscape which is correct. However, the content is 90 degrees wrong, but they are right in the storyboard view, landscape. Is there anything I need to check?

1. I set my storyboard as landscape.
2. May project I already set "supported interface orientations" = landscape
3. Also used this code in view controller:

   ```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
   {
   if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
       return YES;
   else
       return NO;
   }
   ```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - driving me CRAZY!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Initial interface orientation" set in your Info.plist as well.

Comment: Thanks, I did but still don't work. I recreate a new project with same steps and then it works @@

Answer (score 0):

Supported Interface Orientations is one thing. It didn't work for me until I did the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following code on ALL of your viewcontrollers

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
        return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
}
```